# "from captcha.fields import RecaptchaFields" Is not recognized by Pylance

Tags: python, django

making a Django project and wanted to use Google's Recaptcha API in order to fight off bots.

I've followed several installation KBs, watched tutorials, and I'm using these two as my installation guide:
https://pypi.org/project/django-recaptcha/
https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Despite following their instructions, none of them seem to be importing correctly, Pylance doesn't recognize 'captcha' when importing in a form.py file. I'm even copying and pasting from their website just for this post's sake.

```
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
```

These seem to be what I need in order to properly set up the API - I've even placed in the correct secret keys. The problem seems to be when I attempt to use it on a form/model .py file.

Yes, I have installed in in installed apps - it's simple:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "captcha",
]
```

I have even tried:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'captcha',
]
```

Not sure if load order has anything to do with the issue, and most tutorials seem to have the widget working right after this step.

I have also made sure to set the `urls.py` files up according to the KB:

```
urlpatterns += [
...,
path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
...,
    ]
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin several times now, that isn't doing anything. I can see the package in the env\Lib\site-packages directory.

> > pip uninstall django-simple-captcha
> > pip install django-simple-captcha

No dice.

edit:
As a side note, I also checked in the forms.py file if the other modules are importing. I have bootstrap4, whitenoise and other packages installed and they are all recognized and can be called upon. They all rest in the same env/Lib/site-packages directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - but it may be a bug with VSCode not routing the module correctly. Things are working on the front-end and and the keys are working. The env console was giving me the "from captcha.fields" error but it seems to be happy now.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If so please accept your own answer.