# "from captcha.fields import RecaptchaFields" Is not recognized by wagtailcaptcha

Tags: python, django

I run my app on docker, and lately, I the web container does not start due to this error

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtailcaptcha/models.py", line 4, in 
> from .forms import WagtailCaptchaFormBuilder, remove_captcha_field
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtailcaptcha/forms.py", line 4, in 
> from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'captcha.fields'

I have captcha in installed apps, and wagtail-django-recaptcha 1.0 in my requirements.txt. I dropped the container and recreated it but still see the issue.

I've read up on different posts including ["from captcha.fields import RecaptchaFields" Is not recognized by Pylance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74092594/from-captcha-fields-import-recaptchafields-is-not-recognized-by-pylance) but still I could not resolve the issue.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/77737125/10951070

Comment: It did not help, I still see the error

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution was to update forms.py and change the line

```
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
```

to

```
from django_recaptcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
```